# How to exclude portions of text when copying

Tags: html, css, noncopyable

Im trying to make some text non-copyable, my aim isn't to stop people from copying text from my website but more to make it easier to use. I have a list of files with file size's but I want to only copy the file names and not the file size.

So far i'v tried a few different methods but non have worked, I have managed to get the text non-selectable with CSS user-select but I can still copy the file size when I select two or more rows.

I just tried using a button to prevent the copying, which didn't work ether, any ideas?

```
<a href="http://10.10.10.1/links/file.doc"file.doc</a>
 <button type="button" disabled="disabled" id="filesize">6 MB</button><br \>
```

Target browser is Safari on the Mac, so experimental CSS3 or HTML5 commands that work on the latest Safari is fine.

(Thanks mvds for the suggested title, and one solution)

Comment: will the browser copy contents of an `<input type="text" style="border:0;" value="(6 MB)">` tag?

Comment: It does not! (unless I select inside the box, but thats ok the text can be copied if the use wants) Put this in an Answer below so I can credit you. Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate it, thanks! The downside is still that you have to do quite some formatting on an input to get the exact same layout as normal text, cross browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly hack alert: create 2 versions of your text, one with and one without the sizes, otherwise identical, and put them in overlapping divs, with the version without sizes having a higher z-index.

The better solution, maybe not cross-browser, is to add an

```
<input type="text" value="(6 MB)" style="border:0; ...">
```

I suggest renaming the question "how to exclude portions of text when copying" because as it stands now, it sounds like you're looking for the average hopeless copy-protection scheme, while the question is quite interesting.

Answer (score 3):

A fairly hacky method to make this work is using `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements to insert your text using css `content:` property.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://10.10.10.1/links/file.doc">file.doc</a>  
<button type="button" disabled="disabled" id="filesize"><i></i></button>
```

**CSS:**

```
button i:before {
 content: '6 MB';
}
```

**Pros:** It works: it doesn't get copied to the clipboard even when selecting multiple rows.

**Cons:** Pseudo elements require special care for CSS styling since they are inserted outside the normal document flow. Using the `content:` property for multiple elements would also require custom tags or inline css.

Comment: It works, at least in Chrome and FF. This seems to be the better hack than the one described in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a span (or any text container really) and the `unselectable` attribute, like this:

```
<a href="http://10.10.10.1/links/file.doc">file.doc</a>
<span unselectable="on">6 MB</span>
```

This won't work everything, but since you have a specific browser target, this will work just fine for your situation :)

To easily support a few more browsers while you're at it, you can throw some CSS in there, first define a class like this:

```
.unselectable { 
  user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -khtml-user-select: none; 
}
```

Then assign it as well, like this:

```
<a href="http://10.10.10.1/links/file.doc">file.doc</a>
<span class="unselectable" unselectable="on">6 MB</span>
```

Comment: I tried the user-select method, it will prevent selection but it still copies the text when selecting multiple rows.

Comment: @Mint - Any option you go with will do that, unless you strip it out manually in JavaScript.  If you can select a range, it must be a *continuous range* ...the only option I can think of is for these items to be out of the normal document flow, positioned so they appear in the right place, but aren't in the selectable range.

Comment: mmm yeah, that could be worth a try. Didn't think about it that way.